# Detect click events outside div inside usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a div inside a user control that is displayed by the user after some event.
I want to hide this div when user clicks anywhere elese on the page but not on the div (or not on any element that is inside the div).

If it wasn't a user control I could use body's clieck event to check the target,
but because this is usercontrol that is hosted by other page I can't just "play" with it's elements.

How can I achieve that without using body of the hosting page?

Comment: Remember that whatever is in your user control will be appear as part of the complete page when rendered. So Im thinking you can still exploit the body click event.

Comment: I know I can exploit, but I don't want to because there is an option that body's click event is already used for some other events (hosting page is not "mine")

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't. But it doesn't matter, because you won't overwrite any existing event handler if you use the `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` method instead of the `document.body.onclick="..."` method.

Here is an example using the Prototype library for easier coding: http://jsfiddle.net/uVt7X/